# Удаление строк в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Столкнулся с одной проблемой. У меня есть таблица, в которой по нажатию кнопок можно добавлять, вставлять между существующих строк и удалять строчки. Когда все строки удалены и я снова нажимаю на кнопку удалить, то программа вылетает.

И тоже самое с кнопкой insert. Не могу исправить ошибку. Понимаю, что в коде ошибка, но как реализовать это по другому - не знаю. Пытался прописывать ограничения, тоже ничего не вышло. Буду благодарен за помощь! Вот мой полный код:

**Файл mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mymodel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyModel *Model;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Файл mymodel.h**

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QVector>
#include "sport.h"

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex & index) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
signals:
    //    void editCompleted(const QString &);
public slots:
private:
    QVector<Sport> GridData;
};

#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

**Файл sport.h**

```
#ifndef SPORT_H
#define SPORT_H
#include <QString>

class Sport
{ public:
    Sport ();
    Sport (QString name, QString code);
    Sport (const Sport& v);
    Sport& operator= (const Sport&);

    QString name () const;
    QString code () const;
    float ball () const;
    int mesto () const;

    void setName (QString name);
    void setCode (QString code);
    void setMesto (int m);
    void setBall (float b);

private:
    QString Name, Code;
    float Ball;
    int Mesto;
};
#endif // SPORT_H
```

**Файл mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Model = new MyModel;
    ui->tableView->setModel(Model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //add
    int row = Model->rowCount();
    Model->insertRows(row, 1);

    QModelIndex in = Model->index(row, 1);
    ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(in);
    ui->tableView->edit(in);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    //insert
    int row = ui->tableView->currentIndex().row();
    Model->insertRows(row, 1);

    QModelIndex in = Model->index(row, 1);
    ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(in);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //delete
    Model->removeRows(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row(),1);
}
```

**Файл mymodel.cpp**

```
#include "mymodel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    GridData.resize(1);
}
int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return GridData.size();
}
int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 4;
}
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch (index.column())
        {
        case 0:
            return GridData[index.row()].name();
        case 1:
            return GridData[index.row()].code();
        case 2:
            return GridData[index.row()].ball();
        case 3:
            return GridData[index.row()].mesto();
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant MyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
    {
        switch (section)
        {
        case 0:
            return QVariant("Фамилия участника");
        case 1:
            return QVariant("Код команды");
        case 2:
            return QVariant("Количество балов");
        case 3:
            return QVariant("Место в итоге");
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        //save value from editor to member m_gridData
        //        m_gridData[index.row()][index.column()] = value.toString();
        switch (index.column())
        {
        case 0:
            GridData[index.row()].setName(value.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            GridData[index.row()].setCode(value.toString());
            break;
        case 2:
            GridData[index.row()].setBall(value.toInt());
            break;
        case 3:
            GridData[index.row()].setMesto(value.toInt());
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
Qt::ItemFlags MyModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return Qt::ItemIsEditable | QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
}
bool MyModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginInsertRows(parent,row, row + count - 1);
    GridData.insert(row, count, Sport());
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
bool MyModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginRemoveRows(parent,row, row + count - 1);
    GridData.remove(row, count);
    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

**Файл sport.cpp**

```
#include "sport.h"
Sport::Sport():
    Ball(0.0), Mesto(0)
{
}
Sport::Sport(QString name, QString code):
    Name(name), Code(code), Ball(0.0), Mesto(0)
{
}
Sport::Sport(const Sport &v)
{
    this->Name = v.Name;
    this->Code = v.Code;
    this->Ball = v.Ball;
    this->Mesto = v.Mesto;
}
Sport &Sport::operator =(const  Sport &v)
{
    this->Name = v.Name;
    this->Code = v.Code;
    this->Ball = v.Ball;
    this->Mesto = v.Mesto;
    return *this;
}
QString Sport::name() const
{
    return Name;
}
QString Sport::code() const
{
    return Code;
}
float Sport::ball() const
{
    return Ball;
}
int Sport::mesto() const
{
    return Mesto;
}

void Sport::setName(QString name)
{
    this->Name = name;
}
void Sport::setCode(QString code)
{
    this->Code = code;
}
void Sport::setBall(float b)
{
    this->Ball = b;
}
void Sport::setMesto(int m)
{
    this->Mesto = m;
}
```

Comment: Кода очень много и нет желания в нем копаться, лучше в вопросе оставлять [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
`Когда все строки удалены и я снова нажимаю на кнопку удалить, то программа вылетает.`? Не нажимайте кнопку, когда таблица пустая -- блокируйте кнопку удаления (`setEnabled(false)`) когда таблица пустая, дополнительно. А в методе удаления проверяйте что вью/модель не пустая. PS. в таких случая используйте отладчик или накидайте по строчно вывод в консоль -- чтобы определить место падения

Comment: Спасибо. (setEnabled(false)) я использую. Но не могу подобрать точное условие, чтобы когда таблица была пуста, кнопка была не активна, а когда снова добавляются строки - опять активна. Всегда у меня блокируется после одного нажатия..

Comment: В MainWindow сделайте метод updateStates, в нем для ваших виджетов пропишите условия. Например для кнопки это будет `button->setEnabled(Model->rowCount())`. Вызывайте эту функцию в конструкторе, в методе добавления и удаления. В общем, в местах, которые могут изменить состояние виджетов. Другой вариант -- подцепиться к нужным сигналам и на них обновлять: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую!

Comment: button->setEnabled(Model->rowCount()) Этот метод для удаления получилось реализовать. Когда строк нет, то кнопка неактивна. Но когда снова их добавляю, то она также остаётся неактивной. Не могу сообразить, как это исправить. Для кнопки insert данный метод не работает.

Comment: В методе, что добавляет строки вызывайте код, который вызывает `button->setEnabled(Model->rowCount()) `. Нашел у себя пример: https://github.com/gil9red/PaintNodes/blob/09070fe8ef7d5077d8464e725bf45acd81d217a2/mainwindow.cpp#L25

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался! Всё получилось!

Comment: Добавьте в ответ что сделали, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        //add
        int row = Model->rowCount();
        Model->insertRows(row, 1);

        QModelIndex in = Model->index(row, 1);
        ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(in);
        ui->tableView->edit(in);
        ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(Model->rowCount());
        ui->pushButton_2->setEnabled(Model->rowCount());
    }

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {
        //insert
        int row = ui->tableView->currentIndex().row();
        Model->insertRows(row, 1);

        QModelIndex in = Model->index(row, 1);
        ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(in);



    }

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
    {
        //delete
        Model->removeRows(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row(), 1);
        ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(Model->rowCount());
        ui->pushButton_2->setEnabled(Model->rowCount());

    }
```